# Python3 CSV encoding problems

Tags: python-3.x, csv, encoding

I'm trying to add some information to a row in a CSV-file, but in the updated CSV-file the special characters (², ±) aren't encoded well. Let me clarify:

So basically I have a CSV-file with the following example row:

```
row = ["Some info", "Cell with special characters (², ±)", "Some more info"]
```

I'm trying to add some text to the second column, so I wrote the following code

```
import csv
new_rows = []

# Open CSV file
with open('file_1.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f1
    reader =  csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        # Add text to cell, save row to memory
        row[1] = row[1] + " is causing trouble"
        new_rows.append(row)

# Write rows in new CSV-file
with open('file_2.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', newline='') as of:
    writer =  csv.writer(of, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

The output in the second column I expected would be as follows:

```
"Cell with special characters (², ±) is causing troubles"
```

But instead I get the following output:

```
"Cell with special characters (??, ??) is causing troubles"
```

I tried to solve the problem by changing the encoding to Latin-1, or even by not mentioning the encoding in the code at all, but nothing seems to work!

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: I could not reproduce the error. So there is probably something wrong with how you check your output, or your environment.

Comment: The issue might be that you're using `UTF-8` while the special characters are `ASC-II`

Answer (score 0):

Your source file is probably latin-1, you are encoding mojibakes to utf-8 in the second file. Your code has nothing wrong.

You just need to decide if you want to produce a latin1 or utf-8 csv ( and maybe add a BOM https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-io/issues/30 ) as a destination after reading the source in the good encoding ( maybe you can check with a hexadecimal dump how it is encoded and give us some clues ).